# Deadlock between a dispatch_sync on the main queue and executeFetchRequest:error:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, deadlock

I am `dispatch_sync()`'ing a block on the main queue. In this block, a call to `executeFetchRequest:error:` is eventually made. Sometimes, this causes a deadlock.

Here is Thread 1 which shows the block invoked on the main thread and then the call to `executeFetchRequest:error:`

```
#0  0x981f3876 in __psynch_mutexwait ()
#1  0x97a016af in pthread_mutex_lock ()
#2  0x0135be32 in -[_PFLock lock] ()
#3  0x0135be0a in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator lock] ()
#4  0x01371d1c in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) lockObjectStore] ()
#5  0x013702c0 in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
#6  0x0000a701 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(Convenience) fetchObjectsForEntityName:onlyIDs:withPredicate:] at /Users/mike/Dropbox/src/Tracky-iPhone/Tracky/Tracky/NSManagedObjectContext(Convenience).m:50
#7  0x00065270 in +[NSManagedObject(ContextAdditions) contextForID:managedObjectContext:] at /Users/mike/Dropbox/src/Tracky-iPhone/Tracky/Tracky/NSManagedObject+ContextAdditions.m:40
#8  0x0006597e in __85+[NSManagedObject(ContextAdditions) createContextIfNeededForID:managedObjectContext:]_block_invoke_0 at /Users/mike/Dropbox/src/Tracky-iPhone/Tracky/Tracky/NSManagedObject+ContextAdditions.m:55
#9  0x00065aad in __85+[NSManagedObject(ContextAdditions) createContextIfNeededForID:managedObjectContext:]_block_invoke_050 at /Users/mike/Dropbox/src/Tracky-iPhone/Tracky/Tracky/NSManagedObject+ContextAdditions.m:64
#10 0x023cf8d9 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke ()
#11 0x023d0509 in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF ()
#12 0x01ae9803 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x01ae8d84 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x01ae8c9b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x019b47d8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#16 0x019b488a in GSEventRun ()
#17 0x004ba626 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

I can see that `executeFetchRequest:error:` is blocking on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s lock, but I don't know who currently has it locked.

The original `dispatch_sync()` is occurring from a different thread, and here's that in case it's important:

```
Thread 18, Queue : (null)
#0  0x981f1c5e in semaphore_wait_trap ()
#1  0x023d1bda in _dispatch_thread_semaphore_wait ()
#2  0x023d0cb2 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow ()
#3  0x023d0e0f in dispatch_barrier_sync_f ()
#4  0x023d0f4c in _dispatch_sync_slow ()
#5  0x0006563a in +[NSManagedObject(ContextAdditions) createContextIfNeededForID:managedObjectContext:] at /Users/mike/Dropbox/src/Tracky-iPhone/Tracky/Tracky/NSManagedObject+ContextAdditions.m:63
#6  0x0006e2ee in __109-[ItemFetcher createOrConfigureObjectWithDescriptor:withContext:jsonObjectIDKey:modelObjectIDKey:entityName:]_block_invoke_0 at /Users/mike/Dropbox/src/Tracky-iPhone/Tracky/Tracky/ItemFetcher.m:78
#7  0x023ce330 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#8  0x023cff0c in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#9  0x023cfcb4 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#10 0x023cf402 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#11 0x97a04b24 in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

Here is the code up to the original dispatch:

```
+ (Context *) createContextIfNeededForID: (NSString *) contextID managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) moc
    {
    // See if this context is in the main MOC. This call needs to happen synchronously on the main queue, if we're
    //  not on the main queue
    Context * (^contextFromMainMOCBlock)(void) = 
        ^ `Context` * {
        // We are guaranteed to be in the main here; look at how this block is invoked.
        return [self contextForID:contextID managedObjectContext:[UIApplication trackyAppDelegate].managedObjectContext] ;
        } ;

    __block Context *contextFromMainMOC = nil ;

    if( [UIApplication trackyAppDelegate].managedObjectContext == moc )
        contextFromMainMOC = contextFromMainMOCBlock() ;
    else
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            contextFromMainMOC = contextFromMainMOCBlock() ; // <-- here
            }) ;
…
```

`contextForID:contextID managedObjectContext:` really doesn't do anything with core data until it calls `executeFetchRequest:error:`.

**UPDATE**

Here are the rest of the stack traces. AFAIK they're not doing anything interesting although I may be wrong.

```
Thread 3, Queue : (null)
#0  0x981f490a in kevent ()
#1  0x023d0372 in _dispatch_mgr_invoke ()
#2  0x023cebe1 in _dispatch_mgr_thread ()
Thread 5 WebThread, Queue : (null)
#0  0x981f1c22 in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x981f11f6 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x01b8610a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01ae95d5 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x01ae8d84 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x01ae8c9b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x04776420 in _ZL12RunWebThreadPv ()
#7  0x97a02ed9 in _pthread_start ()
Thread 6 com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader, Queue : (null)
#0  0x981f1c22 in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x981f11f6 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x01b8610a in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x01ae95d5 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x01ae8d84 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x01ae8c9b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x00ebae30 in +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] ()
#7  0x00dcc4d6 in -[NSThread main] ()
#8  0x00dcc447 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#9  0x97a02ed9 in _pthread_start ()
Thread 10 com.apple.CFSocket.private, Queue : (null)
#0  0x981f3b42 in select$DARWIN_EXTSN ()
#1  0x01b1a7cb in __CFSocketManager ()
#2  0x97a02ed9 in _pthread_start ()
```

And here is `contextID:managedObjectContext:` which is the method called in the `dispatch_sync()` :

```
+ (Context *) contextForID: (NSString *) contextID managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) moc
    {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cid == %@", contextID] ;
    NSSet *contexts = [moc fetchObjectsForEntityName:@"Context" onlyIDs:NO withPredicate:predicate] ;

    // Integrity check
    NSAssert1(contexts.count < 2, @"More than one context with the same CID exists: %@" , contexts) ;

    return [contexts anyObject] ;
    }
```

`fetchObjectsForEntityName:onlyIDs:withPredicate:` looks like this:

```
- (NSSet *)fetchObjectsForEntityName:(NSString *)newEntityName onlyIDs: (BOOL) onlyIDs
    withPredicate:(id)stringOrPredicate, ...
    {
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
        entityForName:newEntityName inManagedObjectContext:self];

    NSAssert1( entity != nil , @"entity not found for \"%@\"" , newEntityName ) ;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setIncludesPropertyValues:!onlyIDs] ;

    if (stringOrPredicate)
        {
        NSPredicate *predicate;
        if ([stringOrPredicate isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            {
            va_list variadicArguments;
            va_start(variadicArguments, stringOrPredicate);
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:stringOrPredicate
                arguments:variadicArguments];
            va_end(variadicArguments);
            }
        else
            {
            NSAssert2([stringOrPredicate isKindOfClass:[NSPredicate class]],
                @"Second parameter passed to %s is of unexpected class %@",
                sel_getName(_cmd), NSStringFromClass(stringOrPredicate));
            predicate = (NSPredicate *)stringOrPredicate;
            }
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
        }

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results ;
    @try {
         results = [self executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception caught: %@" , exception) ;
    }

    if (error != nil)
        {
        [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"%@",[error description]];
        }

    return [NSSet setWithArray:results];
    }
```

Comment: Try `dispatch_async()` then this code won't sit waiting

Comment: What are the other threads doing? Also, I agree with Paul.s somewhat. The philosophy of GCD is that you should avoid synchronous dispatch whenever you can. The problem is that you've designed an API which returns data to its caller which then acts on that, so it has to be synchronous.  Instead, there should be a block to process the data when it is available.  The caller can pass that in, allowing the whole operation to be asynchronous.

Comment: I agree with both of you as well. The code was originally written without blocks and GCD, and if this works it will keep most of the interfaces intact. But maybe it's going to take a massive refactor.  Fun.

Comment: thks @Paul.s! `dispatch_async()`really did the trick

Comment: Have you ever resolved this, @leftspin? I'm getting the same `__psync_mutexwait` because of the deadlock, and I am running in `dispatch_async()`. Care to share what you did to fix it?

Comment: No sorry it's still unresolved. Had to back out and am trying a different architecture.

Comment: Similar question (Does this help) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576280/core-data-freeze-at-fetch-request-deadlock?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

To give more help, you need to show the code for all methods in the stack traces, along with line numbers.  That way, it can be correlated.

Also, it looks like you have a lot of threads.  I think you are going to have to examine the others to see what is happening.

You have to be very careful when calling a sync operation, especially if it may be called from other sync operations.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `NSManagedObjectContext` for `concurrencyType`.  It seems that your context has `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, which runs all requests in the main thread. From **[Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSMainQueueConcurrencyType)**:

> NSMainQueueConcurrencyType
>
> Specifies that the context will be associated with the main queue.

If I'm right you need to change type to `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`